# Is there a way to zoom in camera in Teams / Webex / other Online meetings

Tags: camera, microsoft-teams, webex

I used to use the camera integrated in the laptops' display: As Laptops are usually quite near my face almost completely filled the picture of the cam in online meetings.

Now I have an external monitor attached and a camera on top of it. This camera (brand: aukey) is much further away and now shows almost the complete room, and my face is only a small spot in the camera image.

I tried and search but could not find any setting, to "zoom in" on my face.

Is there any software / setting / etc. to zoom in the camera image indepdendant of the brand of the camera?

If it only works for MS Teams then I am already satisfied, as 90% of my meetings is teams...

Comment: The camera manufacturer usually makes something with at least rudimentary control.